# If make isn't supposed to run as root, then how can I install a policy file?

Tags: make, polkit

I understand that a Makefile should not require the user to be root. So I'm using `/usr/local` like this:

```
PREFIX=/usr/local

install:
    install -D example $(PREFIX)/bin/example
```

That works fine. But I also need to install a policy file for polkit. And the only valid path for those is `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/`. If I try to use `install`, I get the following error:

```
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.example.policy': Permission denied
```

How am I supposed to install my policy file if I can't ask the user to run `make` as root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's customary that *building* a program doesn't require root access, but *installing* it often does. So it's pretty normal to run

```
make
sudo make install
```

Or, when building software to include into a package, something like:

```
make
mkdir install-root
fakeroot -- sh -c 'make PREFIX="$PWD/install-root/usr/local" install && cd install-root && tar -czf ../package.tgz .'
```

Comment: ... and for extra bonus points, support `$(DESTDIR)` as well as `$(PREFIX)`.